# Cloudify Influxdb port 8086 down

Tags: influxdb, cloudify

I have a issue that is: In my Cloudify Manager, InfluxDB ver 0.8.8 service is still working but port 8086 is down so could not access to InfluxDB to query or update data.

Im stucking in that causes dont know why, some hero has any ideas for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which blueprint you used to bootstrap. None of the blueprints open port 8086 in the security group. You need to open it yourself if you want to be able to query the influx API yourself or from another app. Internally, I think it is using 8083.

Comment: I also have no port 8083. Problem is my monitoring service (grafana) was still working well but it was died suddenly, so when I checked then port 8086 was down